# Ear detection using opencv

Tags: opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, haar-wavelet

I am trying to detect ears in a profile image(side view) of face.I tried using harrcascades (haarcascade_mcs_rightear,haarcascade_mcs_leftear,left_ear.xml,right_ear.xml) provided in opencv.I am able to detect profile face.But I am not able to detect ears with any one of haarcascade.I am specifying region of interest using profile face detector.I am not able to find out where i am going wrong.Please help me with that.A code snippet for the same would be of great help.Thanks in advance.Following is the code with comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
CvMemStorage *storage;
int detectFeature(int,char *imname,IplImage* image,CvRect featureROI, Rect* feature_box);
const char *file_profileface = "haarcascade_profileface.xml";
const char *ear_profileface = "left_ear.xml";//cascade name
CvRect profile_face;
CvRect ear;
int main()
{
int flagFaceDetect;
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
assert(storage);

Rect faceRect;Rect leftEar;Rect rightEar;
char myimage1[50];

sprintf(myimage1,"profile%d.jpg",1);
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(myimage1, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
/*first detect profile face and then detect ears*/

Rect* rectptr = &faceRect;//rectangle for profile face
CvRect face_roi = cvGetImageROI(img);
flagFaceDetect = detectFeature(0,myimage1,img,face_roi,rectptr);

rectptr = &leftEar;
//set ROI for ear with respect to profile face rectangle
CvRect leftear_roi = cvRect(faceRect.x+faceRect.x*3/4,faceRect.y+faceRect.height /4,faceRect.x+faceRect.width+faceRect.width/10,faceRect.y+faceRect.height-faceRect.height/4);
flagFaceDetect = detectFeature(1,myimage1,img,leftear_roi,rectptr);



getch();
return 0;
 }

int detectFeature(int feature_index,char *imname,IplImage* image,CvRect featureROI, Rect* feature_box) {//general function to locate feature
     cvSetImageROI(image, featureROI);
     CvSeq* feature;
     CvHaarClassifierCascade* featureCascade;
    if(feature_index==0)//cascade for profile face
     featureCascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*) cvLoad(file_profileface, 0, 0, 0);
    if(feature_index==1)//cascade for ear
        featureCascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*) cvLoad(ear_profileface, 0, 0, 0);
  // feature = cvHaarDetectObjects(image,featureCascade,storage,1.1,2,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(50,50));
    feature = cvHaarDetectObjects(image,featureCascade,storage,1.2, 3,0,cvSize(18,12));
     cvResetImageROI(image);
     IplImage* displayImage = cvLoadImage(imname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
     CvRect* r;
     int index_max_area;
     int x1, x2, y1, y2; // opposite vertices of the rectangle


     if (feature->total == 0) {
         cout<<"here";
             return 0;
     }
     else {

         CvRect *fture = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(feature, 0);
         feature_box->x=fture->x;
         feature_box->y=fture->y;
         feature_box->height=fture->height;
         feature_box->width=fture->width;
          /* draw a red rectangle around the feature*/
          cvRectangle(displayImage,
                                cvPoint(fture->x+fture->x*3/4,fture->y+fture->height/4),
                                cvPoint(fture->x+fture->width+fture->width/10,fture->y+fture->height-fture->height/4),
                                CV_RGB(0, 0, 255),
                                1, 8, 0
                               );



             cvShowImage("frame",displayImage);
             cvWaitKey(0);
             return 1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @herohuyongtao:added the code

Comment: Did you copy the xml files to the `Debug/Release` folder?

Comment: Or try to use full path of the xml files.

Comment: @herohuyongtao:yes i am using full path (not shown in code) but still it didnt work.

Comment: @herohuyongtao:when detectFeature function is called for ear it prints "here" and returns that means feature is not detected.

Comment: Did you succeed in this code, I am facing the same problem. I am able to detect the profile face but none ogf the ears are getting detected.Can you suggest?

Comment: Did you succeed in this code? Facing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried **detectMultiScale()** function of opencv?

Comment: The profile face detector generally doesn't include the ear in the resulting region of interest, so if you are trying to detect an ear in the profile face you just detected, that's probably not going to work. 

Try using the ear detector before the profile face detector, and use them independently.

Comment: One more thing, the right / left seems to be reversed when using the haarcascade_mcs_rightear and haarcascade_mcs_leftear data;  if one doesn't work, try using the other.  For me this was counterintuitive.